# Multi-value Form Parameters Not Decoded When Lein Ring Uberwar Deployed to Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, clojure

I have built a Clojure web app using ring/compojure. Some forms have inputs offering multiple selections. When running locally with the jetty server these are presented as vectors of values in the `:params` map as expected, however when deployed to Tomcat only one of the selected values appears.

project.clj:

```
(defproject bconfig "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "BConfig Web App"
  :url "http://example.com/bconfig"
  :dependencies [
                  [org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                  [compojure "1.1.8"]
                  [hiccup "1.0.5"]
                  [com.oracle/ojdbc6 "11.2.0.3"]
                  [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.3.3"]
                  [cheshire "5.3.1"]
                  [clj-detector "0.0.2"]
                  [org.clojure/data.xml "0.0.7"]
                  [org.apache.commons/commons-compress "1.8.1"]
                  [digest "1.4.4"]
                  [net.sf.uadetector/uadetector-resources "2014.04"]
                  [org.flatland/ordered "1.5.2"]
                  [environ "0.5.0"]
                  [propertea "1.3.1"]
                ]
  :plugins [
             [lein-ring "0.8.11"]
             [lein-environ "0.5.0"] ; ensures :env section below becomes available to environ.core/env
           ]
  :ring {:handler bconfig.handler/app
         :url-pattern "/"
         :servlet-name "bconfig"
         :web-xml "web.xml"
        }
  :repl-options {
             ;; If nREPL takes too long to load it may timeout,
             ;; increase this to wait longer before timing out.
             ;; Defaults to 30000 (30 seconds)
             :timeout 120000
             }
  :profiles {:dev {:dependencies [[javax.servlet/servlet-api "2.5"]
                        [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.3.0"]
                        [ring-mock "0.1.5"]
                       ]
                   :env {
                        }
                   :jvm-opts ["-Denv=dev" "-Ddevmode=y"]
                   :resource-paths ["resources" "resources/local"]
                   :source-paths ["src" "src/jetty"]
                  }
             :deploydev
                  {:resource-paths ["resources" "resources/ldndsr000005176"]
                  }
            }
)
```

Snippet from handler.clj:

```
(def app-routes (wrap-base-url the-routes))

(def app
  (handler/site app-routes))
```

Tomcat is 6.0.24 on RHEL with servlet api version 2.5. What might this issue be?

Answer (score 1):

Ok - may be ring/jetty does decode to vectors in `:params` while under tomcat not so, but `:multipart-params` is always OK.

Use the source, Luke